# xslt removing punctuation

Tags: xslt, translate

Can anybody tell me why the following line of code wouldn't be a legitimate way to remove periods and commas for the text node of paragraph element using xslt 1.0? Here's the template I currently have:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:p">
    <p id="{@xml:id}" class="plaoulparagraph" style="margin-left: 3em;"><xsl:apply-templates select="./translate(current(), '.,', '')"/></p>
</xsl:template>
```

My editor is currently giving me an error when I try to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:apply-templates select="./translate(current(), '.,', '')"/>
> ```

**In XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 the expression in the `select` attribute of `xsl:apply-templates` must evaluate to a node-set**.

The `select` attribute of the above instruction is syntactically invalid in XPath 1.0 because in XPath 1.0 it isn't allowed to have a function call as the RHS of the `/` operator (Thanks to @MichaelKay for pointing this) and in XPath 2.0 it evaluates to a string, not a node-set -- and this is the cause of the error.

**You want to do something like this**:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:p//text()">
 <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '.,', '')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**and replace the quoted above instruction with**:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
```

Comment: Moreover, in XSLT 1.0 you cannot have a function call on the rhs of the "/" operator.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Thanks for the good observation -- I added this additional error to my explanation.

Comment: Ha -- that's a very clever solution. It seems to work -- however, I assume that if <p> has children with punctuation I'll need to run separate templates to remove punctuation as well - say for a <quote> which is a child of <p>, i.e. `tei:quote//text()`

Comment: @Jeff: Actually you *don't* have to do that. `tei:p//text()` matches all text nodes that are descendands of `tei:/p` .

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<p class="plaoulparagraph" style="margin-left: 3em;"><xsl:value-of select="translate(current(), '.,', '')"/></p>
```

Comment: I thought about this roue, but I'm not sure this will give me what I want. There are many children elements contained with the p tag -- so I want to make sure to apply-templates on all the children of the p as well. If only select the value of P -- then I'm not sure those other more specific templates get processed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with commas of a number you can translate it like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="string_value">
   <xsl:value-of select="'123,456,789.01'"/>
</xsl:variable>

<Number>
    <xsl:value-of select="number(translate($string_value,',',''))"/>
<Number>
```